# How to parse UTF8 string using SwiftyJSON?

Tags: json, swift, string, swifty-json

I am trying to parse string in JSON format using SwiftyJSON but I am unable to parse and access the elements.

My code:

```
if let myString = String(bytes: response, encoding: .utf8)
{
    print(myString)

    let myJSON: JSON = JSON(stringLiteral: myString)

    if let hostName = myJSON["host"].string
    {
       print(hostName)
    }
    else
    {
       print("Cannot parse JSON")
    }
}
```

output of 'myString':

> {"Epoch":1550772995,"host":"MSDN-XXX","port":99999,"whoami":"Server"}

I am unable to parse hostName from myJSON using SwiftyJSON. It prints "Connot parse JSON" right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace this line:

```
let myJSON: JSON = JSON(stringLiteral: myString)
```

By this line:

```
let myJSON: JSON = JSON(parseJSON: myString)
```